# Querying an integer field by just checking the last x digits

Tags: ios, core-data, ios8

I have an integer field in the format YYYYMMDD, and I want to return all records made on a certain day of the month. Is there a way to perform this arithmetic within a NSPredicate so it is translated into SQL (for optimised lookups)?

Basically I need to perform the operation: `(identifier - floor(identifier / 100) * 100) == day`, or `identifier % 100 == day` (whichever ends up being a faster comparison), but this doesn’t seem to work within an NSPredicate. You can't seem to perform mathematical operations in the predicate.

Alternatively, is there some way to cast a field as a string within the query? So I can use ENDSWITH?

It's an sqlite store so I think some of the predicate comparison functions (blocks mainly) can't be used, as they're restricted to in-memory stores.

Any info on how to perform this efficiently would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you keeping date data in a date type?

Comment: These date identifiers are standardised and used throughout our application, they're wall-clock dates (i.e. not points in time from the epoch), and without times. The question still remains regardless of what the integer represents. We need to efficiently query based on the last x digits of an integer.

Comment: @Rob Sadly I don't think you can use predicateWithBlock with an SQLite store.

Comment: Ooh, @Rob is right. This actually works, and it's a hell of a lot simpler than the `NSExpression` magic I was thinking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try the `ENDSWITH` syntax.

SQLite tends to transform between numeric and string types fairly transparently.

Comment: Ah, this works, as long as the value you are comparing with as a string, not another integer. So `x ENDSWITH 25` doesn’t work, but `x ENDSWITH “25”` does. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are in a difficult place because you really should treat that as a date object with a zero time reference, etc.

In a second option if it was just a string then life would be pretty easy too.

Having it as an integer makes your predicate rough.

Just shooting from the hip but have you tried treating it as a string?  SQLite doesn't really care although Core Data might complain about it.

Is this an existing app or do you have the opportunity to change the data model?

Comment: We could change the data model, however working with the value as an NSDate will be impractical. We turn the value into date components and it’s used throughout the app like that, so an integer is the best and most efficient way of encoding date components. But treating it like a string and comparing it with another string does indeed work, good shot from the hip!